# Screen saver created with QCView not working in Snow Leopard

Tags: cocoa, osx-snow-leopard, screensaver

I have prepared a screen saver with QCView using this block of code:

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(NSRect)frame isPreview:(BOOL)isPreview
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame isPreview:isPreview];
    if (self) {

        qcView = [[QCView alloc] init];

        if (!qcView) {
            NSLog(@"could not create qc view");
        }

        [qcView setAutostartsRendering:YES];

        if ([qcView loadCompositionFromFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"AwayMessage" ofType:@"qtz"]] == NO) {
            NSLog(@"Could not load");
        }

        [qcView setFrame:[self bounds]];
        [self addSubview:qcView];

        [self setAnimationTimeInterval:1/30.0];
    }
    return self;
}
```

> Problem is - when I am trying to see it in system preferences, it is
>   showing me this message: **You cannot use the SampleScreenSaver with
>   this version of Mac OS X. Please contact the vendor to get a newer
>   version of the screen saver.**

I am using following configurations to compile it using Xcode 3.2.5:

Architectures - Standard (32/64-bit Universal)

Base SDK - Mac OS X 10.6

Valid Architectures - i386

C/C++ Compiler Version - GCC 4.0

Can anyone suggest solution for it?

Comment: What is written to the console when you see this message?

Comment: one more thing.. if I don't use QCView it works fine.. but if I use it gives stated message